# Mathematica package for explicit matrix representations of group generators?

Tags: linear-algebra, packages, group-theory

While there are several packages that are capable of working with weights and roots (for example [LieArt](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6379)), I couldn't find any package that spits out explicit matrices for the generators, for example for $SO(n)$ or $SU(n)$, in various bases. Specifically, I'm looking for the $SO(10)$ generators in the standard basis and the Cartan-Weyl basis.

Does such a package exist somewhere?

Comment: Once you have explicit generators, split is not a problem, because you always can use trace formula (1/d) Tr(A B) to ,,project'' given matrix A onto the generator B (d being matrix dimension). For larger groups, however, generators can be chosen in many ways.